# Plotting with folium

Tags: python, json, folium

The task is to make an adress popularity map for Moscow. Basically, it should look like this:

https://nbviewer.jupyter.org/github/python-visualization/folium/blob/master/examples/GeoJSON_and_choropleth.ipynb

For my map I use public geojson: http://gis-lab.info/qa/moscow-atd.html

The only data I have - points coordinates and there's no information about the district they belong to.

**Question 1:** 
Do I have to manually calculate for each disctrict if the point belongs to it, or there is more effective way to do this?

**Question 2:**
If there is no way to do this easier, then, how can I get all the coordinates for each disctrict from the `geojson` file (link above)?

Comment: Re question 1, I would leverage something like Geopandas that can consume geojson files and has a function called sjoin that you could use to determine which district your coordinate is within.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @BobHaffner, I tried to solve the problem using geopandas.

Here are my steps:

1. I download a `shape-files` for Moscow using this link [click](http://gis-lab.info/data/mos-adm/mo-shape.zip)
2. From a list of tuples containing `x` and `y` (`latitude` and `logitude`) coordinates I create list of `Points` [(docs)](http://geopandas.org/data_structures.html?highlight=point)
3. Assuming that in the dataframe from the first link I have polygons I can write a simple loop for checking if the Point is inside this polygon. For details read [this](https://automating-gis-processes.github.io/2016/Lesson3-point-in-polygon.html).

Comment: Hi, do you have a solution?

Comment: Ps. you're on the right track.  step 3 could be done with an sjoin

Comment: @BobHaffner step 3 cannot be done at all. When I use `.contains()` method, it comes out that there is no polygon in my json that contains any of my points. That is very strange.

Comment: hmmm.   When you create your Points in step 2, make sure you're passing coordinates in the correct order (longitude, latitude)  I've made that mistake before :-)

Comment: Ok, I'll post a solution that may or may not help

Comment: @BobHaffner, sir, can we connect somewhere? I also got some troubles with geocoding.

Answer (score 1):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import geopandas as gpd
from shapely.geometry import Point
```

Reading in the Moscow area shape file with geopandas

```
districts = gpd.read_file('mo-shape/mo.shp')
```

Construct a mock user dataset

```
moscow = [55.7, 37.6]

data = (
    np.random.normal(size=(100, 2)) *
    np.array([[.25, .25]]) +
    np.array([moscow])
)
my_df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['lat', 'lon'])
my_df['pop'] = np.random.randint(500, 100000, size=len(data))
```

Create Point objects from the user data

```
geom = [Point(x, y) for x,y in zip(my_df['lon'], my_df['lat'])]

# and a geopandas dataframe using the same crs from the shape file
my_gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame(my_df, geometry=geom)
my_gdf.crs = districts.crs
```

Then the join using default value of 'inner'

```
gpd.sjoin(districts, my_gdf, op='contains')
```